# AOS (animate-on-scroll) elements invisible on static site

Tags: javascript, html, css, animate-on-scroll

I'm making a site for a client and trying to implement AOS library to make it look more dynamic.
I've followed instructions from the [GitHub](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos) :

Add to `<head>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" />
```

Add before `</body>`

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
  <script>
    AOS.init();
  </script>
```

No luck. I've applied `data-aos="fade-in"` to a div in the Services section of [this site](https://fightfitness.co/#services) (it should be obvious with the missing box) and it doesn't display at all for me.

Can anyone help?

Thank you,

Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked at the site and I think it has something to do with this css:

```css
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This also caused a double scrollbar for me, you should remove those two lines.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks so much. Do you know why this causes the issue?